# How to get the data from mongoose query from one js file to another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have tried to get the data from mongoose query which is return in another js file I have used promise in one js to find the data from one collection,and I have called in another js.

My code:

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  FindinCol1: function() {
    console.log("Inside promise")
mongo.configuration.findOne({}).exec()
    .then(function(user){
   //   var result = [];
   console.log("user");
     resolve(user);
    })
    .then(undefined, function(err){
     console.log(err)
        })
     }
};
```

route.js

**update**

```
     var siteconfig = require('./config');


      siteconfig.FindinCol1().then(function(items) {
  console.info('The promise was fulfilled with items!', items);
}, function(err) {
  console.error('The promise was rejected', err, err.stack);
});
```

I don't know what mistake i have done.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: cannot read property of then of undefined

Comment: any of the console statements got printed?

Comment: siteconfig.FindinCol1(function(items) {
  console.log(items);
});  I have tried this , now i didn't get error but value is printing in config.js but not in route.js

Comment: add a return before "mongo.configuration.findOne"

Comment: am getting The promise was fulfilled with items!', undefined in routes.js,In config.js am getting the values

Comment: Thank you so much added return inside mongo query as well as before mongo , Not its working thank you so much :):):)

Comment: Cool! glad it helped...

Comment: One more doubt,can i able to use that value globally in route.js?

Comment: No, everything is function scoped. You can declare a var in the beginning of the file and assign it where you receive the items

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand,could you please give example from  my code itself

Comment: declare a variable somewhere at the top of the file - var myVariable; and just before console.info('The promise was fulfilled with items!', items); assign it to items - myVariable = items; Now you can use myVariable anywhere in your file. Just note that it will be undefined till is assigned.

Comment: I have assigned, eventhough it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is not the undefined resolution of a promise, but rather an undefined value returned by a function that doesn't return anything.

You must return the promise created by `findOne({}).exec()`

```
module.exports = {
    FindinCol1: function() {
        console.log("Inside promise");
        // notice return...
        return mongo.configuration.findOne({}).exec()
        .then(function(user){
            console.log("user");
            return user;  // no need for "resolve" here, which looks undefined anyway
        })
        .catch(function(err){  // use catch for errors
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
};
```